# Confusion about Provider with multiple Consumer Widgets

Tags: flutter, dart, provider

I am confused about Provider. I think Provider is meant to encapsulate the state of a Widget so it can be accessed somewhere else throughout the program. The problem is: What if I want a certain stateless widget multiple times? I created an example for this:

Lets say we want to model a few pieces of paper. Each piece of paper has some unique writing on it. I could now make a provider for a single piece of paper like this:

```dart
class PaperSheetProvider extends ChangeNotifier {
  String uniqueText = "";

  void setUniqueText(String newText) {
    uniqueText = newText;
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

and I make a simple paper widget to consume that provider like:

```dart
class PaperPieceWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaperPieceWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PaperSheetProvider>(
      builder: ((context, value, child) => Text(value.uniqueText)),
    );
  }
}
```

and at last, I make 2 paper widgets along with a button to change the text of the paper:

```dart
Column(
  children: [
    PaperPieceWidget(),
    PaperPieceWidget(),
    OutlinedButton(
      onPressed: () {
        Provider.of<PaperSheetProvider>(context, listen: false).setUniqueText('blablaablaa');
      },
      child: Text("change paper contents"))
  ],
),
```

(The ChangeNotifierProvider is near the root of the whole widget tree to simplify the code a bit)

Simple enough. But now If I click the button, I get:
[image]

Basically, the two paper pieces have the same writing. Which should not be the case, each piece of paper should have their own, unique writing. How do I do this correctly?

Full code in case anything is unclear:

```dart
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  static const String title = 'Shortcuts and Actions Demo';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: title,
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Column(
        children: [
          PaperPieceWidget(),
          PaperPieceWidget(),
          OutlinedButton(
              onPressed: () {
                Provider.of<PaperSheetProvider>(context, listen: false)
                    .setUniqueText('blablaablaa');
              },
              child: Text("change paper contents"))
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

void main() {
  runApp(MultiProvider(providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: ((context) => PaperSheetProvider()))
  ], child: const MyApp()));
}

class PaperPieceWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  const PaperPieceWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<PaperSheetProvider>(
      builder: ((context, value, child) => Text(value.uniqueText)),
    );
  }
}

//(provider is posted entirely above)
```

Comment: i guess you dont even understand how to use provider then... you basically asking why the value of the same provider wrapping the same widget is the same? you should use the unique text as a list then.. there is many ways to do this i think.. try learn more about provider instead..

Answer (score 0):

Wrap each widget with own provider. Something like this:

```
PaperSheetProvider provider1;

ChangeNotifierProvider.value(
  value: provider1,
  child: PaperPieceWidget(),
)
```